# Wordpress - Could not load the preview image. Please reload the page and try again

Tags: php, wordpress

When I try to rotate a picture in the Wordpress media library, I get this error message:

**Could not load the preview image. Please reload the page and try again.**

What could be the problems that I get this message?

I have read some other Q&A about this problem and a solution is to remove empty space after end of "`<?php /*code or comment*/ ?>`" or debug but this is not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

In my particular case functions.php of my theme was involved.
Just remove empty space after end of `"<?php /*code or comment*/ ?> "`
There should be NO empty space between `"<?php ?>"` tags.

[You can find more info:](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/basic-image-editor-not-working/)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks but I've already tried this solution but it's not working for me:-(

Comment: Same thing for me <?phpSPACE which I could not see. Deleted, all good.

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the closing tag as recommended in [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php).